# Do we say "lift your left leg off the floor" when you just actually fold the shin and make it parallel to the ground?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Ok, look at the picture, there are 2 movements

[image]

The first movement, the person seems to lift his leg off the floor, the knee goes forward and the thigh & the shin form a triangle.

The second movement, the thigh is kept fixed & the shin is folded & make itself parallel to the ground.

**How do we express the 2nd movement in English?**

Comment: It seems odd to me to say, "Lift your leg off the floor" when your leg is not on the floor when you're standing. *Leg lifts* are exercise done when you're either prone or supine. In the first movement, you raise your knee; in the second, you raise your heel. Because of the way human joints work, those expressions should be ambiguous.

Comment: @user105719, when we say "raise your heel", people may think the heel still contact the floor like in this picture https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPGdT5pEEOj0OAVqiPIysorO4l3MpirAB1x47-RcqrdBGUewpDfQ&s

Comment: The context would be important. In speech or in writing? Who would be talking to who, where, why, etc.? Are you looking for an imperative/instruction, or a description? 

If someone was looking at me, I might say *Do this* while demonstrating. For reason such as these, I think this question needs more details to be productive.

Comment: Possibly. There's little that cannot be misunderstood, but your picture is of someone "raising his heels," and no heel is in contact with the floor there.

Comment: @user105719 "Lift your heel" is a strange request, and if someone were to ask me that, my toes would still be touching the ground. "**Bend one leg while standing**", would be clearer.

Comment: I would call (1) lifting your _foot_ off the floor. (2) could perhaps be described as "raising the foot so that the lower leg is parallel to the floor".